# Stream closed showing up in play framework 1.2.5

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

i have an application that want to write a file using fileoutputstream

**here's the code, method patch**

```
public static Response patch() {
    try {
        System.out.println("PATCH");
        System.out.println(request.contentType);
        String file = params.get("filename");
        System.out.println("patch file: " + file);
        Map<String, Header> MapOffset = request.headers;
        for (Entry<String, Header> entry : MapOffset.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Header['" + entry.getKey() + "]: "
                    + entry.getValue().value());
        }

        Header offsetParam = MapOffset.get("offset");
        Long offset = 0L;
        if (offsetParam != null) {
            offset = Long.parseLong(offsetParam.value());
        }

        InputStream input = request.body;
        File f = new File(UPLOAD_DIR + System.getProperty("file.separator")
                + file);

        System.out.println("address: " + f.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("offset: " + offset);
        System.out.println("length: " + f.length());

        fileBasicUpload(f, offset, input);

        Response respon = new Response();
        respon.status = OK;

        return respon;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

**and this is where i write a file**

```
private static void fileBasicUpload(File f, Long offset, InputStream input)
        throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream output = null;
    try {
        int c = -1;
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        try {
            output = new FileOutputStream(f, true);
            while ((c = input.read(b)) != -1) {
                output.write(b, 0, c);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    } finally {
        output.close();
    }
}
```

but when my application called, then stream closed error is show up at `while ((c = input.read(b)) != -1)` that line.
i don't know how that error is called. sorry for my poor english and thanks

Comment: Why not simply use `play.libs.IO.write(InuptStream, File)` method or something from Apache Commons IO. It should work just fine and you would have fewer lines of code to bugfix later on :)

Comment: i didn't know there's lib like that in play, maybe i should try it :)

Comment: i have tried it and it still stream closed error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer. in my application i found like this

```
 public static Response upload(File file){
    System.out.println("Appliaction.upload");
    response = ResumableUpload.post();
    return response;
```

//      render(response);
    }

the parameter file, it must be delete, then it work!